# How to set an start solution in Gurobi, when only objective function is known?

Tags: python, initialization, gurobi, upperbound

I have a minimization problem, that is modeled to be solved in Gurobi, via python.

Besides, I can calculate a "good" initial solution for the problem separately, that can be used as an upper bound for the problem.

What I want to do is to set Gurobi use this upper bound, to enhance its efficiency. I mean, if this upper bound can help Gurobi for its search. The point is that I just have the objective value, but not a complete solution.

Can anybody help me how to set this upper bound in the Gurobi?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you can calculate a good solution, you can also know some bound for your variable even you dont have the solution exactly ?

Comment: Not actually. The only thing I have done is to set a new constraint and set the objective variable less than my upper bound. But I am not sure this is the best way.

Comment: you can put those contraints in the objectf, like lagrangian method. If the MIP dont find a best, it will respect it.